# Strapi: Initialize / populate database

Tags: postgresql, bookshelf.js, strapi

When I deploy Strapi to a new server, I want to create and populate the database tables (PostgreSQL), particularly categories. How do I access production config, and create tables and category entries?

A hint on how-to approach this, would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but i recently came upon the same issue.
Basically you should create the collections first, which result in the creation of models. Of course you also could create the models manually.

In the recent documentation you find a section about a bootstrap function.

[docs bootstrap](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/configurations.html#bootstrap)

The function is called at the start of the server.
The docs list the following use cases:

> Here are some use cases:
>
> - Create an admin user if there isn't one.
> - Fill the database with some necessary data.
> - Load some environment variables.

The bootstrap function can be synchronous or asynchronous.

A great example can be found in the Plugin *strapi-plugin-users-permissions*

You can implement a new service or overwrite a function of an existing plugin.

the function initialize is implemented here [async initialize](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/services/UsersPermissions.js#L339)
and called in the bootstrap function here
[await ...initialize()](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/config/functions/bootstrap.js#L186)

The initialize function is used to populate the database with the two roles
*Authenticated* and *Public*.

Hope that helps whoever stumbles upon this question.